# Turn on <serviceSecurityAudit> dynamically

Tags: wcf

I am looking to set the  element dynamically (in WCF). I want to avoid using a config file.

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
 ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior newAudit = new ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior();
            newAudit.AuditLogLocation = AuditLogLocation.Application;
            newAudit.MessageAuthenticationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
            newAudit.ServiceAuthorizationAuditLevel = AuditLevel.SuccessOrFailure;
            newAudit.SuppressAuditFailure = false;



            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Remove<ServiceSecurityAuditBehavior>();
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(newAudit);
```